# Failing to Get Puppeteer to Work and Install

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, installation, puppeteer

probably a newbie question, but I'm really struggling to get Puppeteer to work. I probably have messed up somewhere in the download, but I just can't figure it out.

My puppeteer version is 5.1.0
Node is v14.5.0
Running on Ubuntu 18.04, though also failed to run on Windows command line
Windows 10

this is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "test_puppeteer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "test.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I try to run this test, and it WORKS for example.com, but no other website and it doesnt properly close
This is my basic screenshot test:

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']})
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

If i run this I get example.png created, but no other feedback, and if i change the site to anything else i get `(node:28737) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a fool, and the answer lies in the messed up permissions of my own computer. It's probably not great in the long run, but when I ran puppeteer in file folders placed on my desktop, i had no problems, Ignore this!